# Weired exception in signalR related to type System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr.client

Created a server signalR application successfully and I am able to view the created JavaScript code template by navigating to http://localhost:11914/signalr/hubs.

The client application is a .NET 4.6.2 web api created with the recent template by Visual Studio 2017 latest RC. When I execute the code below:

```
    var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:11914");
    var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("cache");
    hubProxy.On<CachedObjectInfo>("sendUpdateNotification", cachedObject => RefreshMemory(cachedObject));
    await hubConnection.Start();
```

I receive the exception below in when hitting `await hubConnection.Start();`

```
type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.'
```

The client singalR application leverages Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client version 2.2.1 package.

I have no idea why I should be receiving such an exception and I could not find any solutions. What's the root cause and how to mitigate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's an issue with the System.Net.Http package version. More specifically, if you have v4.1.1 - v4.3.0 installed for the project you run then you will run into this issue when you target .NET 4.6.1 or 4.6.2. See [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100) for more details. To fix this issue, they released a new package, System.Net.Http 4.3.1, that should get rid of the error.